# MVC Separation of Concerns

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

so I was going on creating my MVC 3 web app when it dawned on me that I might be putting entirely too much logic in my Controller, that it needs to be in the Model instead. The problem with this is, that in this particular instance I'm dealing with a file.

The SQL database table stores the path of the file, and the file itself is saved in a directory. So in the database, the file path is stored as an nvarchar, and in the model, the file is a string, everything's consistent to that point. The issue comes when it's time to upload the file, at that point I'm dealing with a System.IO.File.

So the question is, how do you provide System.IO.File logic inside the model for the file when in the back-end it is actually a string?

I had finished the functional version of the Controller and had some logic already in it, and was about to add more when I realized that I was working against the system. What I mean is that in order to have server-side validation, the logic needs to be in the Model in order for the input validation to behave and work according to proper MVC rules, obviously optionally using client-side validation in conjunction.

Currently...

Here is my View:

```
@model ProDevPortMVC3.Profile

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Profile Photo Upload";
}

<h2>Photo Upload</h2>

<img alt="Profile Image" src="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProfilePhotoPath)" />

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadPhoto", "Profile", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <br />
    <input  type="file" name="File1" />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ProfilePhotoPath)
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
}
```

Here is my Controller (just the relevant action method):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadPhoto(int id, FormCollection form)
    {
        Profile profile = db.Profiles.Find(id);

        var file = Request.Files[0];

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                string newFile = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/Content/users/" + User.Identity.Name + "/" + newFile));
                profile.ProfilePhotoPath = "/Content/users/" + User.Identity.Name + "/" + newFile;
                UpdateModel(profile);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

And here is my Model (just the part relevant to the file):

```
    public string ProfilePhotoPath { get; set; }
```

So I guess, what are your guys' solutions in these particular situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Description

Assuming i understand your question. I have read your question a few times. ;) If i don't understand, please comment my answer in order to get a better answer (i will update)

I think that you want is.. How to Model Validation for your particular case.

You can add Model Validation errors using the `ModelState.AddModelError("Key", "Message)` method.

> **ModelState.AddModelError** Adds a model error to the errors collection for the model-state dictionary.

#### Sample

```
ModelState.AddModelError("ProfilePhotoName", "YourMessage");
```

This will affect `ModelState.IsValid`

So you can do whatever you want (*your logic*) and can make your Model invalid.

#### More Information

- [MSDN - ModelStateDictionary.AddModelError Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.addmodelerror.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I this will be just the solution I am looking for... I did not of AddModelError. That will allow me to throw custom errors depending on the issue at hand. Now I have to figure out how to work with the file in the System.IO.File sense, in the Model, considering it's a string.

Comment: Does my answer help ? Consider to accept but only if this is that you was looking for. I am always glad to help. All the best to you!

Comment: What I meant to say is that this will solve part of the problem, the server-side validation issue...

Comment: I am sorry if i don't understand your whole question. What else you try to do?

Comment: Well, in the Model, how can I set the allowable FileTypes and Maximum FileContent size, with it being a string? Because that is where the rules need to be in place, I just can't figure out how to go about doing it in the Model...

Comment: Really hard to understand for me right now, i am sorry. But what you can do is to pass the ModelState to your method which contains the rules. Or (and this is better in order of seperation of concert) you return a dictionary "Property" "Message" and add this to ModelState.AddError.

Comment: This part I understand, "But what you can do is to pass the ModelState to your method which contains the rules" ... because basically that's what I'm already doing... The second part, "you return a dictionary "Property" "Message" and add this to ModelState.AddError" ... I don't understand... But it looks like you have quite of experience from your profile, so if you say it's OK to put some of the logic inside of the Controller, at least in special circumstances, then that's what I'll do...

Comment: What the second part means is "Do not return someting that is specific to the technology you are using". Example. If you doing someting that uses "ModelState" it will result in a MVC Web-Application. If you really want "Seperation of concern" you should think that your method could call from any kind of application (Web, Windows Forms, WPF, Windows Mobile, Windows Phone, ... a Webservice). So, how to get this done?, find the way that every application can handle. So in your case the best way is returning something that is availiable in every .NET app. I am tired ;) but would you like to chat ?

Comment: Sorry, you cant go to chat right now, not enough reputation (says stackoverlow).

Comment: Ok, well thanks for all of your help... I'll see if I can get the rest figured out...

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of answers to this question.  I'll take a crack at it knowing the risk going in due to varying opinion.  In my personal experience with MVC3 I like to use flatter, simpler Models.  If there is validation that can be done easily in a few lines of code that doesn't require external dependencies then I'll do those in the Model.  I don't feel like your System.IO logic is validation, per se.  Validation that could go in the Model, in my mind, is whether the filename is zero length or not.  The logic to save is something you can put in your controller.  Better yet, you could inject that logic using the [Inversion of Controller](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/InversionOfControl.htm) pattern and specifically a [Dependency Injection](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/) solution.

Comment: When you say, " I don't feel like your System.IO logic is validation, per se." and then say "Validation that could go in the Model, in my mind, is whether the filename is zero length or not." ... That's kind of contradictory, unless I'm misunderstanding you correctly?

Comment: I can determine if the filename is zero length using System.String.  I wouldn't have to use System.IO for that simple validation need.

Comment: True that, I thought you were going on the lines of being able to tell if it is the correct FileType and what-not...